# What do you mean by the ‘computational model’ of a programming language?

Tags: language-design, language-comparison

What do you mean by the ‘computational model’ of a programming language?

Are ‘abstract machines’ such as Stack, RAM, and *Warren Abstract Machine (WAM)* examples of computational models?

Is the *computational model* related to the *operational semantics* of a programming language?

I’ve seen answers here link the ‘computational model’ and ‘operational semantics’.

PS I have one PL textbook that is pretty recent(PLAI) but it doesn’t mention computational model at all - so any text recommendations would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of where you see the phrase "computational model" being used? I don't find anything searching that exact phrase here.

Comment: “Simultaneously to the notion of FRP, Hughes [1991] developed the notion of Arrows, a restricted computational model consisting of reified functions joined together by combinators.” - https://felleisen.org/matthias/7480-s21/lectures.html - sorry this is the first use I could find

Comment: I doubt that there's a single, specific meaning for that phrase. But someone who is more familiar with this should answer. To me, it means something like "the fundamental abstractions that the language/DSL is built upon." That is close to "abstract machine" but maybe a bit more, well, abstract and high-level. Another similar instance of that phrase being used is in [The Art of the Propagator](https://dspace.mit.edu/handle/1721.1/44215), describing how you can build programs out of "propagators" (a sort of cell that gains information over time which can be combined into highly concurrent nets)

Comment: I’ve found https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-are-the-basic-computational-models and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/what-is-computational-model - but these resources sadly lack any references.

Comment: Is it helpful to rephrase the term as "model of computation", which means no more or less than what those words all mean on their own? Or are you looking for something more specific somehow, and if so, what? Who is "you" in the question?

Comment: I don't think either had a clear definition, but are you asking about computational model (or [model of computation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_of_computation)), or you already know that, but only asking about how it is used for a programming language?

Comment: I'm surprised this question still has no answer. I'm tempted to write up a bad answer in hopes someone will correct it.

Comment: I think this definition is probably about as good as it gets (from Andrej Bauer's [currently unfinished monograph on realizability](https://www.andrej.com/zapiski/MGS-2022/notes-on-realizability.pdf)): "A *model of computation* describes what computation is and how it is done." This is from the start of Chapter 2 which is titled "Models of Computation".